# How to make Win 10 direct all requests to single ip/domain through network adaptor #2?

Tags: networking, windows-10, ethernet, subnet

This is my setup:

[image]

I wish to have Computer A use the ethernet (network adapter) and **never** use the wifi when attempting to communicate to Computer B (and vice-versa).

Best case scenario:

1. Domain lookup -> use ip of 10.0.0.x, subnet 255.0.0.0
2. SSL verification (Certificate Authorities) -> skip it and just trust that the server is correct
3. Access to the server -> use the ethernet, never use the wifi. **No** interaction with the router, since it's rather far away
4. Any sort of "network sharing" between the two computers use ethernet

How might I go about doing this? I'm rather new to the whole network connecting bit.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone can give a better, more detailed answer but a few thoughts (and please forgive me if I touch on things you are already aware of or make any mistakes =P)...

*Ethernet-Only Networking*

In order to connect Computers A and B directly via Ethernet, you will likely need a crossover Ethernet cable or a regular Ethernet cable with crossover adapters. You will also likely need a secondary Ethernet card in both, as this kind of setup requires a static IP (*10.0.0.1*, *10.0.0.2*) to be assigned manually for each card. Subnet masks are set per card as well.

*Domains and SSL*

I am a bit confused here. I am going to assume you mean you want Computer A to contact Computer B with a domain such as *example.com* (which always maps to e.g. *10.0.0.2*). In this case, the simplest route is likely just to modify your *hosts* file on Computer A with:

```
10.0.0.2    example.com
```

Note that some software may need special configuration to listen on multiple adapters (assuming you also want some programs on the server to be accessible via e.g. *192.168.1.51*). Regarding skipping SSL verification, the best way to bypass it is not to use it (establishing non-SSL connections may or may not necessitate additional software configuration as well).

*Access The Server Via Ethernet Only*

The best way to do this is by specifying an IP address (e.g. *10.0.0.2*) to connect to. The same thing applies if you are going the other way (e.g. connecting from *10.0.0.2* to *10.0.0.1*).

*Network Sharing*

Windows network sharing is usually based on networks (that is, like the one that would be established using the crossover cable), so it seems unlikely you would have too many issues here (at least for default Windows sharing). That said, as hinted at in the other paragraphs, you may be at the mercy of software/hardware and its ability to be configured to isolate something completely it on your Ethernet-only network.